# Plotting 3D waves with parametric equations

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I'm trying to plot these curves.

[image]

[image]

I tried this using the code below. But, the output wasn't exactly what I wanted. I couldn't extend it to the negative X-values and couldn't mark those ticks on the axes.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[margin=15mm,a3paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.707cm,0.707cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},y={(-0.866cm,0.5cm)}]

\draw[->] (-5,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[right] {x};

\draw[->] (0,-2,0) -- (0,2,0) node[left] {y};

\draw[->] (0,0,-4) -- (0,0,4) node[above] {z};

\draw (1,0,0)

\foreach \z in {0,0.1,...,4}

{ -- ({\z},{sin(\z*150)},{2*cos(\z*150)})};

\node[rotate=90,right=1cm] at (0,0,12) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

This was my output.

[image]

For the second one, I've no idea how to do. It seems like a cosine function though. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plots in 3d can, unsurprisingly, be made with `tikz-3dplot`. You can always add a parametric plot using the plot path construction, e.g.

```
\draw plot[variable=\t,domain=-4:4,samples=101,smooth]
  ({\t},{sin(\t*150)},{2*cos(\t*150)});
```

Strictly speaking you do not need `tikz-3dplot`, I use it merely to get an orthographic view, i.e. to spare you from having to guess something like `x={(0.707cm,0.707cm)},z={(0cm,1cm)},y={(-0.866cm,0.5cm)}`. The `perspective` library also allows you to install a 3d view.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{125}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line cap=round,>=stealth]
 \draw[->] (-5,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[pos=1.05] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-5,0) -- (0,5,0) node[pos=1.05] {$y$};
 \draw[->] (0,0,-4) -- (0,0,4) node[pos=1.05] {$z$};
 %
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=-4:4,samples=101,smooth]
  ({\t},{sin(\t*150)},{2*cos(\t*150)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line cap=round,>=stealth]
 \draw[->] (-5,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[pos=1.05] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-5,0) -- (0,5,0) node[pos=1.05] {$y$};
 \draw[->] (0,0,-4) -- (0,0,4) node[pos=1.05] {$z$};
 %
 \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=-4:4,samples=101,smooth]
  (0,{\t},{sin(\t*150)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much!